# How to emulate Raspberry Pi in 2024

Tags: emulation, qemu

I followed roughly this tutorial: https://www.ravbug.com/tutorials/virtual-rpi/

I used the versatilepb approach and tried to move to bullseye and replaced the Variables of the script accordingly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

KERNEL=./qemu-rpi-kernel/kernel-qemu-5.10.63-bullseye
DTB=./qemu-rpi-kernel/versatile-pb-bullseye-5.10.63.dtb
DRIVE=2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-armhf.img

qemu-system-arm -kernel "${KERNEL}" \
    -cpu arm1176 -M versatilepb \
    -dtb ${DTB} \
    -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
    -drive "file=${DRIVE},index=0,media=disk,format=raw" \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22 -net nic
```

The folder `qemu-rpi-kernel` is a submodule in my git project of the repo mentioned in the tutorial and the image is downloaded from the raspios archives.

I am able to boot the system with a few errors. At the end I am stranded with a not connected qemu-screen and a login mask. At that point I stumbled over the no-default-password topic and I am out of ideas how to manage the system.

I've also tested the original buster configuration which works perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but one way to work around the "no-default-password topic" would be to use writable loopback mounts of the two partitions in your file 2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-armhf.img.  You can edit /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/group, and /etc/gshadow along with adding an entry in /home to create a user that either does not require authentication or requires you to enter a password on first login.  You are constrained by the available space on the partitions in the .img file, but that should not be a problem.  Then when you get to your login screen impasse, you can login.